# Terraform heredoc with variable string and ":"

Tags: terraform

It seems that terraform is having difficulty with ":" in my variable string. I tried escaping it with "\" but the error persists. simply removing ":" causes the error to disappear. How can I use ":" in my variable string heredoc?

```
::: variables.tf :::
variable "values" {
  type    = "string" 
  default = "<<EOF
    key:
      key:
        key: value
    EOF"
}

$ terraform apply
...
Error loading modules: module testmodule: Error parsing .terraform/modules/9f0444507ebf595a0777cb4d34430176/variables.tf: At 4:8: illegal char
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the syntax, if you write **`<<EOF`** inside double quotes then it will be identified as a single line string. Multi line strings should start with `<<EOF` and not `"<<EOF`

Rewrite it as

```
variable "values" {
  type    = string 
  default = <<EOF
    key:
      key:
        key: value
    EOF
}
```

It will work

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on TF 0.14.4 :\, If I add output "result" { value = var.values }, and run terraform plan the result includes the <<EOF instead of working like a heredoc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913451/heredoc-syntax-for-variable-values has a working example